# Active directory service with office 365

Tags: active-directory, office365

I run a small business with 3 employees and dont want to spend a fortune on this IT solution. But I would like to have an active directory service so that I can admin the users from a central place. Get benefits with domain policys like password lengt requirment and so that they need to update the passwords evry now and then. I would also love if its some how integrated with our office365 so that users doesnt need to sign-in specifically to office 365 (Single sign on?).

Is there an easy way to setup this either with office365 so that I can use the active directory service in office 365 or with a realtive easy way with some other directory service ?

The employees in the business are not located in an office, they travel quite much, so an internal active directory installation is not an option.

If someone can point me to a tutorial I would be very greatfull.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the very common solution i had done the same http://thecloudmouth.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/wp-adfs-o365-iaas.pdf

or the best alternative is 
https://process.st/2014/04/small-business-in-the-cloud-google-apps-or-microsoft-office-365/